# Android Studio - Set Notification Led

Tags: java, android, android-studio, notifications

I'm trying to use a Notification LED on my application during run time. For example I would like the led to blink with yellow color, but for some reason my code is not working and the led does not changed (It is always off).

I am testing the code on Nexus 5 and Nexus 9

Here is my code:

```
    void setLed(Context context) {
        NotificationManager notificationManager = ( NotificationManager ) context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE );
        Notification notification = new Notification();
        notification.defaults = 0;
        notification.ledARGB = Color.YELLOW;
        notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        notification.ledOnMS = 500;
        notification.ledOffMS = 500;
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
    }
```

Please advise.

Comment: is your device screen on when notification is coming ?

Comment: I've tried both when the screen is on and off

Comment: I found the root cause for my issue. The problem occurs both in Nexus 5/Nexus 9. However, on Sony Z3 it works good.